# How to open emacs-nav buffer in the right-hand window?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When opening [emacs-nav](http://code.google.com/p/emacs-nav/), it splits the window and puts the nav buffer on the left-hand side. I would like it to go on the right-hand side instead. And maybe make its buffer width constant.

Sadly I can't find any docs for it.

Comment: Are you referring to this: http://code.google.com/p/emacs-nav/ ?

Comment: Okay. You need to provide links when referring to non-standard libraries. People can't help you if they can't be sure what you're asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see at the bottom of [nav.el](http://code.google.com/p/emacs-nav/source/browse/nav.el) that `(nav)` calls `(split-window-horizontally)` which leaves the left-hand window selected, and then proceeds to call `(nav-in-place)` which changes that selected window to the nav window.

So using the right-hand window isn't really supported; however, assuming that nothing else needs to call `nav-in-place` (certainly it's not referenced anywhere else in that file), we could advise it to switch to the other window before acting.

```el
(defadvice nav-in-place (before my-nav-in-other-window)
  "Start Nav in the other window, after splitting."
  (other-window 1))
(ad-activate 'nav-in-place)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems proposed solution not works anymore.

I have to redefine whole nav function

```
(defun nav-right ()
  "Run nav-mode in a narrow window on the left side."
  (interactive)
  (if (nav-is-open)
      (nav-quit)
    (delete-other-windows)
    (split-window-horizontally)
    ;;(other-window 1)
    (ignore-errors (kill-buffer nav-buffer-name))
    (pop-to-buffer nav-buffer-name nil)
    (set-window-dedicated-p (selected-window) t)
    (nav-mode)
    (when nav-resize-frame-p
      (nav-resize-frame))))
```